# jenkins ssh to a server is unable to store as a variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh

I have Jenkins set to say server1 and I have created a Jenkins job that ssh to server 2 and print the path using pwd. The code is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x
ssh server2 """pwd"""
```

It prints the home path of server 2 as expected. Now I want to store the path into a variable. I tried the code below :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x
ssh server2 """var = $(pwd)"""
```

Here the result is not as expected as the output is the path of Jenkins home in server1 and not home path of server 2. How do I store the home path of server2 ?

Comment: can you share your pipeline code? what plugging are you using for remote ssh executions?

Comment: I am not using any plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On shell scrip the way for storing the output from a remote host execution should be something like this:

```
result=$(ssh server2 "pwd" 2>&1)
```

Don't know how you plan to capture this and use it on your pipelines but it might be more useful to consider using [ssh agent](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) plugin or [ssh](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/) plugin.

At the same time as pointed out in your comment, having spaces on your variable declaration in bash is incorrect
`var = $(pwd)` should be `var=$(pwd)`

Comment: ```$(ssh server2 "pwd" 2>&1)```  did work but I came across this  error result: command not found

Comment: That does not make much sense, can you execute the same command from the shell of your jenkins server?, is the target server 100% UX one? if you are trying to connect this way I assume you have public/private key in place for doing such thing and a configuration in place on your jenkins .ssh for doing so with a default user or something.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to shell scripting the error was because of space  after '=' sign